# Select a href present within particular div tag

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I need to select the anchor tags present in the div tag where id=content.
I used the following code in java

```
Element lin = doc.getElementById("tag#content");
Elements links = lin.select("a[href]");
```

But when I debug the program lin=Null.

I also tried the below code but lin was still null.

```
Elements lin = doc.select("div#content");
Elements links = lin.select("a[href]");
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<ul class="nolist">
<li><a href="/undergraduate/"><h3>Undergraduate Study</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="/graduate/"><h3>Graduate Study</h3></a></li>
<li><a href="/currentstudents/course/current/"><h3>Courses</h3></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Elements links = doc.select("div#content > ul > li > a");

for (Element e : links) {
       System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
}
```

Which will output:

```
/undergraduate/
/graduate/
/currentstudents/course/current/
```

---

In regard to your comments, I tried this:

```
String html = "<div id='content'><ul class='nolist'><li><a href='/undergraduate/'><h3>Undergraduate Study</h3></a></li><li><a href='/graduate/'><h3>Graduate Study</h3></a></li><li><a href='/currentstudents/course/current/'><h3>Courses</h3></a></li></ul></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements e = doc.select("div#content a");
System.out.println(e.toString());

Elements f = doc.select("div#content > ul > li > a");
System.out.println(f.toString());
```

Got this output:

```
<a href="/undergraduate/"><h3>Undergraduate Study</h3></a>
<a href="/graduate/"><h3>Graduate Study</h3></a>
<a href="/currentstudents/course/current/"><h3>Courses</h3></a>
<a href="/undergraduate/"><h3>Undergraduate Study</h3></a>
<a href="/graduate/"><h3>Graduate Study</h3></a>
<a href="/currentstudents/course/current/"><h3>Courses</h3></a>
```

Comment: still null.this is what i ran `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(startLink).get();
       Elements links1 = doc.select("div#content > ul > li > a");

    for (Element e : links1) {
           System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
    }`

Comment: the thing is `doc.select("div#content")` is giving me null

Comment: @user1556718 Oh ok my code works if I just parse your example html as a string. Try print out `doc.toString()` just to check if it is receiving the correct html. Can you share the web url of this html?

Comment: any University site. Eg:syr.edu/admissions/ and <div id="container"> or http://cse.uta.edu/research and <div id="content">

Comment: @user1556718 Now I can see why the `("div#content > ul > li > a")` wouldn't work - it's because there is another div inside `div#content` on the actual page, so the hierarchy was wrong in the select statement. Instead you need `("div#content > div > ul > li > a")` to make it work that way, though `("div#content a")` will still work too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this :

```
Element lin = doc.getElementById("tag#content");
```

Comment: lin is still null `Element lin = doc.getElementById("tag#content");
    Elements links = lin.select("a[href]");`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I was using wrong URL.
The below Code worked
`doc.select("div#content a");`
But `doc.select("div#content > ul > li > a");` gives me null any reason why?

Comment: Hmm interesting. I would think that both ways should both work, but I guess it depends on the structure of the html. The first example will select child elements that descend from an ancestor, e.g. any `<a>` that descend from `<div id="content">`. The second example selects child elements that descend directly from parent (or hierarchy). See [this link](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) and read about selector combinations.

Comment: In fact, using ONLY the html you provided in your original question (`Jsoup.parse(html)`), both ways do work. I just tested it, see my updated answer.